# Benefits of Using Datasets

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable, dataset

I understand that datasets contain datatables and that they can house the relationships between those datatables. I am making a simple form that gets data from SQL Server by way of stored procedures that return the records I need subject to certain parameters. It is not strictly necessary that I model relationships between the datables. Are there other benefits of using a dataset to contain them, or am I just as well off to leave them free standing?

Comment: Just an opinion, but never liked them. Have a look at Entity-Framework

Comment: IMHO datasets are a perfectly usable technology that has fallen foul of two of Microsoft's very common faults - they are massively under-documented, and they were released before they were quite finished, so there's a few rough edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can automatically perform actions on related tables (autodelete). Or you can add restrictions which will depend on such relations.
And it will help you to draw a database diagram.

Comment: Yes, I am eager to start using them in this way - but in the current application I am just parking a few unrelated tables in the dataset, or else just let the datatables stand on their own. I am intrigued by the database diagram.

Comment: On databases with a small amount of tables (up to five-ten) this feature is really irrelevant. But when you have a monstrous DB with 100+ tables and gigabytes of data, database diagram (so as other benefits) could really help.

Comment: If you don't need to navigate via the datarelations, then don't include them. eg if you want to fill a dataset with all orders for one customer, and all order items for those orders, you'd probably also want to use the datarelation to select the order items for one order. Conversely, if you only pull one order, and its corresponding set of order items, then nothing is gained by having the datarelation.

Comment: @PeterG  - My approach has been to let SQL Server do all the heavy lifting and just feed VB what it needs for the UI - but I wonder if constructing a more complicated data structure in memory via datasets would not pay off in fewer calls to the server, fewer stored procedures needed, maybe overall fewer lines of code. Don't know what will be the cost in performance. What is your oppinion? Worth moving in that direction?

Comment: @MrBill I'm all for letting the server do what it's designed to do, and not pulling more data than you need. Really it's based on how your UI will actually be used. Nothing wrong with using complex datasets with numerous tables in if it fits the way your app works. Ref datarelations, there's no real penalty for putting them in, even if you don't use them right now, they won't get in the way.